# Who is listening to my iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes

I see that there are 2 people in my school connected to my iTunes library. how would i go about finding out who it is, other than just the ip. Maybe try to figure out like their computer name or something like PersonA's macbook.  I'm also new to apple and all these commands. A walk through would be helpful thank you.

-s

Comment: Play a prank on them in recording a message and look around who is making faces :), or open and use the network utility in your utilities folder.